# C# winforms cast childform as of it's own type

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `MDI` project. I'm using 
 `Form activeForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;`

However, Instead of `Form`, I'm for something like:

```
Forms.Lookup.Grade activeForm = (Forms.Lookup.Grade) this.ActiveMdiChild;
Forms.Lookup.Product activeForm = (Forms.Lookup.Product) this.ActiveMdiChild;
```

...etc

so if  `Forms.Lookup.Grade` is active I want return `activeForm` as  `Forms.Lookup.Grade`

How can I cast active form as of it's own type in generic way instead of using `Switch this.ActiveMdiChild.Name` ?

Thank You 
Mansi

Comment: You can't, these are different unrelated types that only have the Form class in common.  You need to write the desired common behavior into a *interface* declaration and have these classes implemented them.  Now you can cast to that interface type.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type at runtime:

```
Form activeForm = this.ActiveMdiChild;
if(activeForm is Forms.Lookup.Grade) {
  Forms.Lookup.Grade gradeForm = activeForm as Forms.Lookup.Grade;
  gradeForm.SomeMethodOfGrade();
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay,    So, It's basically will end up doing Switch by activeForm.Name... Thought of there is someway Generic in C# will determine the type and return form based on that Type

Comment: @user2769267 No, you don't check the name, you check the type. Generally, in OOP, you don't need this kind of checking, so I suppose something is wrongly designed in your case. Why do you want to know the type of active child?